# Adding Keybinds to IOS with Xcode?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to add functions to IOS through an app (preferably that can be done in Xcode) that also work outside of the app itself? For example (while the app is running in the background) every time a user presses the spacebar in safari, any entered text will be copied to the clipboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No - this is not possible and could lead to apps intercepting sensitive data like bank account password etc. You can receive other notifications like push notifications and gps data though.